# Posting metadata to sharepoint 2016 onpremise : System.Text.DecoderFallbackException with special characters

Tags: c#, rest, sharepoint

I try to create an item with metadatas in a SharePoint list.
One of these metata contains a french "ç" character which makes sharepoint responding with a 500 error, with:
code=-1, System.Text.DecoderFallbackException
value=Unable to translate Unicode character [E7] at index 147 to specified code page.

```
using (var client = new SpWebClient("https://intranet/Gestion") { Credentials = CurrentNetworkCredential })
            {
                var payload = new JObject
                {
                    ["__metadata"] = new JObject { ["type"] = "SP.Data.ListeCommentaireGerantListItem" },
                    ["Language"] = "Français (France)"
                };

                var requestUrl = $"/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('{SHAREPOINT_LIST}')/items";
                Dictionary<string, string> updateHeaders = null;

                var r = client.ExecuteJsonWithDigest(requestUrl, "POST", updateHeaders, payload);
                return Redirect("/");
            }
```

spWebClient is defined [here](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/7eff63ad7d001d0e4c8f), basically it adds all needed headers and simplify auth in a [webclient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

i tried to add "application/json; odata=verbose; **charset=utf-8**" in the header, but same error.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to explicitly set encoding  for posting and getting strings to `UTF8` via [`WebClient.Encoding` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

**Example**

```
using (var client = new SPWebClient("https://contoso.sharepoint.com") { Credentials = credentials, Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8 })
{
    //the remaining code goes here...
}
```